# How to incorporate jquery when using an external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery and would like to use some jquery code for my project. I want to use jquery from the Google CDN in my html file, but I already have a linked external javascript file to it and I don't know how to incorporate the library.
Also, when I want to use code later, do I write it inside the external javascript file or inbetween `<script> </script>` tags in the html document?

Currently my HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="onlineshop.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you reference the JQuery library before your external JavaScript file, you don't have to do anything. Just use `$` as normal. Reverse the order of your two `<script>` references.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="onlineshop.js"></script>
```

And, to be clear, these references do NOT have to be in the `<head>` section of your document. Often, it's a good idea to place them just before the close of the body of the web page (`</body>`), so that the browser can load and parse the HTML content uninterrupted by having to download and parse JavaScript files. This can give your users the appearance of a faster loading page because the UI can appear and become responsive faster than if the scripts were at the top of the page.

Answer (score 3):

Since you'll be using Jquery in your external javascript file. Include the Jquery CDN before it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="onlineshop.js"></script>
```

This will work fine.